# Kruskal-Wallis post-hoc analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test

I am doing a Kruskal-wallis test and am wondering which post-hoc analysis is the most suitable for this? Been reading around and saw people recommend Dunn test. I am just wondering if there is any specific reason to not choosing something like Wilcoxon as they both non-parametric?

Comment: A concern in _post hoc_ testing is to avoid false discovery, repeatedly testing the same data. Using 2-sample Wilcoxon rank sum tests with a significance level below 5% (as determined by Bonferroni's criterion) is certainly a choice. As I recall, Dunn's test has some sort of 'false detection' avoidance built in.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for responding! Is there any resource I could refer to on this detail?

Comment: @BruceET Haha! I hope that will happen. I am not that active in this stack exchange stats, can I expect that user come in soon-ish?

Comment: Have you looked at **Related** posts in the margin of this Question? That might be a useful starting point.

Comment: Sorry, that comment (now deleted) was part of another conversation.

Comment: @BruceET Yes, found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310431/post-hoc-for-kruskal-wallis-test?rq=1), but no explanation as to why Dunn. Anyway, as you said that Dunn test avoid false discovery, does that mean I don't need to use multi comparison correction with Dunn?

Comment: I am not an expert on Dunn's test. Probably used it a few times 50 years ago. Maybe [this](http://derekogle.com/FSA/reference/dunnTest.html), will help. Or one of several other pages Google retrieves for `Dunn test Kruskal-Wallis'.

Comment: A day later and no one has offered comments on Dunn. So I have shown an example using two-sample Wilcoxon tests for _ad hoc_ analysis.

Comment: Dunn's test and the Conover-Iman test (unlike Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon) both (1) use the same rankings used by the Kruskal-Wallis test (i.e. MWW does *not* test the same data as KW), and (2) use a pooled variance estimate implied by the Kruskal-Wallis test (this is akin to using the pooled variance in pairwise *t* tests following rejection of a one way ANOVA). Dunn's test is more widely known that the Conover-Iman test, but the latter is strictly more powerful than Dunn's for pairwise *post hoc* to KW tests.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/434037/why-does-the-kruskal-wallis-test-shows-a-difference-but-wilcoxon-doesnt-find-an?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

As [noted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362487/test-statistic-for-follow-up-procedure-stepwise-step-down-of-kruskal-wallis), in [copious](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141856/what-is-the-difference-between-various-kruskal-wallis-post-hoc-tests/141872#141872) [other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/434037/why-does-the-kruskal-wallis-test-shows-a-difference-but-wilcoxon-doesnt-find-an?rq=1) [places](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/multiple-comparisons-in-a-non-parametric-test/107949#107949) on Cross Validated, the Mann-Whitney (aka Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon) rank sum test is inappropriate as a *post hoc* test following rejection of a Kruskal-Wallis test for two reasons:

1. The Kruskal-Wallis test statistic is based on shared rankings of *all* the data, but the Mann-Whitney test is based on rankings *only* of data for two groups at a time. This means that is a very real sense, the Mann-Whitney is using *different* data than the Kruskal-Wallis test. Dunn's test uses the same data rankings as the Kruskal-Wallis test.  The strictly more powerful than Dunn's test (when used *post hoc*, following a Kruskal-Wallis rejection) but less widely known Conover-Iman test also uses the same rankings as the Kruskal-Wallis test.
2. The Mann-Whitney test does not use an estimate of the pooled variance as implied by the Kruskal-Wallis test's null hypothesis. This is analogous to the pooled variance used in *post hoc* pairwise *t* tests following the rejection of a one way ANOVA. Dunn's test uses an estimate of the pooled variance, as does the Conover-Iman test.

Dunn's test is based on an asymptotic normality (*z* distribution) assumption, while the Conover-Iman test is based on an approximately normal (Student's *t* distribution) assumption, and this is why the Conover-Iman test has more power than Dunn's test.

**References**
Conover, W. J., & Iman, R. L. (1979). [On multiple-comparisons procedures](http://library.lanl.gov/cgi-bin/getfile?00209046.pdf) (Technical Report LA-7677-MS). Los Alamos Scientific Laboratory.

Dunn, O. J. (1964). [Multiple Comparisons Using Rank Sums](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1266041.pdf). *Technometrics*, 6(3), 241–252.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following simulated data:

```
set.seed(325);  n = 30
x1 = rgamma(n, 5, .08)
x2 = rgamma(n, 5, .1)
x3 = rgamma(n, 5, .1)
x4 = rgamma(n, 5, .12)
x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4)
g = rep(1:4, each=n, notch=T)
```

In R, 'notches' in the sides of boxes of boxplots are confidence
intervals for group medians roughly calibrated so that, in comparing
two groups, non-overlapping notches suggest significant differences
in medians. So we guess than a Kruskal-Wallis test will show
differences in locations among the five groups.

```
boxplot(x~g, col="skyblue2", pch=10)
```

[image]

```
kruskal.test(x ~ g)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  x by g
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 18.213, df = 3, p-value = 0.0003975
```

Ad hoc, two-sample Wilcoxon (signed rank) tests show some differences.
The most obvious candidate for a significant difference is Group 1 vs. Group 5.

```
wilcox.test(x1, x4)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x1 and x4
W = 712, p-value = 6.264e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Some other paired comparisons between groups are show significant differences
and some do not:

```
wilcox.test(x1,x3)$p.val
[1] 0.01364983
wilcox.test(x2,x4)$p.val
[1] 0.004313019

wilcox.test(x1,x2)$p.val
[1] 0.1193576
wilcox.test(x2,x3)$p.val
[1] 0.3504292
wilcox.test(x3,x4)$p.val
[1] 0.04788982
```

Beyond the obvious comparison, I have done five tests, so the Bonferroni
method of avoiding 'false discovery' would insist of P-values below $0.01$
in order to be considered significant. Here that amounts to
finding significances only between Gp2 & Gp4.

Because we are using simulated data we know that with sufficiently large
sample sizes in groups we might have found differences between Gp 1 & Gp3, Gp 1 & Gp 2,
and Gp 3 & Gp 4, but according to the Bonferroni criterion we did not.

With any scheme of *ad hoc* comparisons, it is unrealistic to expect to
recover the exact true pattern of differences, unless a power and sample size
procedure has prompted use of enough replications in each group to give
sufficient power for that result.

Because the the four samples are not obviously of the same 'shape' some might
say that the Kruskal and Wilcoxon tests are looking at stochastic domination instead of shift of location. (Very roughly, one distribution dominates another if it tends to give larger values than the other.) By showing empirical CDF (ECDF) plots of the four groups we can try to judge stochastic domination.
A dominant sample will tend to have larger values; hence its ECDF will fall consistently below that of another sample. Here are ECDF plots for the four groups in the current example (colors red, brown, green and blue for groups 1 through 4, respectively).

[image]

```
hdr = "ECDF Plots of Four Groups"
plot(ecdf(x1), col="red", xlim=c(20,140), main=hdr)
lines(ecdf(x2), col="brown")
lines(ecdf(x3), col="green2")
lines(ecdf(x4), col="blue")
```